# Proof verification - $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is irrational

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

This might be a duplicate, but I have not found one on this site.

This is my proof and I was wondering if this proof depends on it's conclusion. Here it is:

Assume $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is rational. Then $\exists p,q \in \mathbb Z (\frac{p}{q} = \sqrt[3]{2})$. Then $$\frac{p^3}{q^3} = 2 \implies p^3 = 2q^3$$
However, $2$ is not a perfect cube, so we have a contradiction.

Comment: How does that last step work? Why do you know that $2$ must be a perfect cube? It's the big step in this theorem, and it requires something more than mere assertion.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews how about invoking the Prime Factorization theorem? If the last statement $p^3 = 2q^3$ is true, then $2|p^3 \implies 2|p$. However, if $2|p \implies p^3 = 2^3*p_1^3*\ldots*p_n^3$. So then $q^3 = 2^2*p_1^3*\ldots*p_n^3$ which is a contradiction since 2 is prime.

Comment: Yep, that's the right proof. But that's a big step to elide from the proof. Unique factorization is the big reason, yes.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews so with the above comment my proof is complete?

Comment: Yes, it's fine with that change.

Comment: BTW, you could also note that $p^3 = 2q^3 = q^3+q^3$ contradicts Fermat's Last Theorem, but of course, that's overkill and not the intent of this problem.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 I thought that there was a counterexample for $n=3$ in Fermat's Last theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you know that $2$ is not a perfect cube?

That is exactly what you are trying to prove. Instead of providing a proof, you have restated what you are trying to prove.

This is not a proof as currently written.

Comment: No, he is trying to prove that $2$ is not a cube of a rational. A "perfect cube" is usually taken to mean the cube of an integer. The step is still mere assertion. (It is easy to prove that $2$ isn't the perfect cube of an integer, using inequalities. It is not clear how he takes $p^3=2q^3$ to imply that $2$ would be a perfect cube.)

Comment: Ah, I took it to mean a cube of a rational. There is nothing that requires $2$ to be a cube of an integer (as you mention in your original comment and edited comment here)

Comment: @mixedmath what about my response to Thomas Andrews in the comments to the original question?

Comment: @SalmonKiller Unique factorization is much stronger than what you are trying to prove. It is sufficient, but not necessary. I routinely ask students to show that $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is irrational in my elementary number theory classes at the start of the course for proof-writing practice. We get to unique factorization about 3 weeks later. I don't know what context you're encountering this problem, but that was the context of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try a similar proof to $\sqrt2$:

$p^3=2q^3$ means that $p^3$ is even and this implies that $p$ is even. Then use this to show that $q$ is even.